# Python - How to stop threads - Not Scrapy

Tags: python, multithreading, web-crawler

I have this crawler which uses Multithreading and it works when crawling af website, but my issue is.

If I tell the crawler to get the first 100 pages of a website it does it but it doesn't stop the threading.

I have setup a thread safe variable that I check all the time, but I can see that it looks likes the crawler ignores the value of the thread safe variable.

So it doesn't stop all the threads they keep running, like they a looking for more pages.

How do I stop all the threads and end the script?

Comment: It would be better if you could show us a piece of your code

Comment: I know @EmanuelL but the script is arount 2000 lines of code, so thats pretty imposible.

Comment: I also faced a similar problem but not with webscraping. I suppose your thread is targeting a function, so make sure at the end of the function there is a `return`, Otherwise it will keep running in the background.

Comment: @EmanuelL that seems like it could be the problem, are you on discord?

Comment: All processes are manageable (if you write manageable). To maintain data integrity and to end the process in a healthy manner, you must type a  "task Manager ". Processes are not run with infinite loops. If you don't have any sync problems, you can do this with at least two flags.